# Displaying an RTSP stream in Kivy, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, rtsp

I'm trying to design a UI so that I can view my CCTV streams whenever there is an activation. I would like to use Kivy within Python.

I have tried a few things, but this is my most recent and most sensible attempt:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.video import Video
import time
 
 
class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
 
        stream = Video(source="rtsp://admin:@10.248.158.35:554/ch0_0.264", play=True)
        return stream
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleApp().run()
```

Unfortunately it still throws up an error:

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <rtsp://admin:@10.248.158.35:554/ch0_0.264>
```

Im guessing the module takes the stream as images, and when it goes to look for the first image, there isn't one because it hasn't come through on the stream yet. I'm also guessing that it doesn't keep trying to get an image after it fails to find the first one either, which is why it doesn't resolve itself. Is there a simple fix or something i'm missing?

Comment: I am not sure on how to solve the issue. However, you could use the 'on_load' callback to see if there are any changes when you turn on the stream after running the app.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to use openCV and have a scheduler pick up the images:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2


class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:@10.248.158.35:554/ch0_0.264')
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        return self.my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```